# What NGINX autoindex_format JSON(P) response fields/format should I expect?

Tags: json, nginx, format, jsonp

The NGINX `ngx-http-autoindex-module` supports a `autoindex_format` directive to change the autoindex response from the default html page to xml, json or jsonp.

The official documentation is extremely brief about the subject and offers no further explanation or rules regarding the JSON(P) response. Also google offers just a handful of relevant search results, none of which provide further insight or even plain examples.

So for json and jsonp, what fields and value-types (or even fixed values) should I expect in the response?
Are there any other rules I should know about when consuming the response and generating html-output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) Module (which produces a directory listing for requests ending with the slash character: `/`) included in NGINX *since version 1.7.9 (released 2014-12-23)* added an [`autoindex_format` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format) that **sets the format of a directory listing**:

> **Syntax:**   **`autoindex_format`**`html | xml | json | jsonp;`
>   **Default:**  `autoindex_format html`;
>   **Context:**  `http, server, location`

*Example* config to enable this feature (for JSON):

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format json;
}
```

When the JSONP format is used then the name of a callback function is set with the `callback` request argument. **If that argument is missing or has an empty value, then the JSON format is returned**.

The JSON(P) response data structure (scheme) is defined as :

```js
callback(  // when format directive jsonp AND callback argument in request
  [ // a single one-dimensional Array (wrap) containing
    { // Objects representing directory entries, structured as:
      "name" :"*"                             //String
    , "type" :"directory"|"file"|"other"      //String, ONLY 1 OF THESE 3
    , "mtime":"Ddd, DD Mmm YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT" //String, RFC1123-date of HTTP-date defined by RFC2616
    , "size" :*   //Integer,  ONLY PRESENT IFF "type":"file" !!!!! 
    } /*
  , { // and repeating the above Object structure for each directory entry
    } */
  ]
); // end callbackFunction-call when jsonp
```

The `"name"`, `"mtime"`, `"type":"directory"` and `"type":"file"` should be pretty self-explanatory.
**Important** to note that the `"size"` field is ONLY present IFF `"type":"file"`, otherwise it is omitted entirely (see examples below) !!

`"type":"other"` deserves some further explanation:
Suppose you did something you'd *never do in production* and set `'root /;'` in the config on a linux system and subsequently index `/dev/` then you'd get directory-entries like:

```js
[
{ "name":"floppy", "type":"other", "mtime":"Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:16:56 GMT" },
{ "name":"loop0", "type":"other", "mtime":"Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:16:56 GMT" }
// and so forth
]
```

There could be other examples for `"type":"other"`, if you know some, please leave a comment!

Special dot-current/dot-parent (`.`, `..`) **and** Dot-files/dot-folders (`.hidden`) are filtered (not present) in the response!
Interesting: special dot-current/dot-parent (`.`, `..`) can be added by your clientside code, just as the `ngx_http_autoindex_module` has hardcoded them into the default html-format response.

Here are two 'raw' response **examples** in their original 'formatting'.
**Note:** response line-endings are hardcoded as `CRLF`.

**JSON (and JSONP without callback):**

```js
[
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 }
]
```

**JSONP (with callback=foo):**
<sub>note: the leading block-comment is part of the JSONP response.</sub>

```js
/* callback */
foo([
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 }
]);
```

A painfully simple snippet consuming a JSONP callback and building a HTML table intended to unambiguously clarify the format:

```html
<script>
function foo(d){
  var i= 0
  ,   L= d.length
  ,   r= '<table border="1" cellpadding="4px" style="border-collapse:collapse"><thead style="border-bottom:4px solid black">\n'
       + '<tr><th style="width:80%">Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Last Modified</th><th>Size</th></tr>\n'
       + '</thead><tbody>\n'
  ;
  for(;i<L;++i)
    r+= '<tr><td>'  + d[i].name
      + '</td><td>' + d[i].type
      + '</td><td style="white-space: nowrap">' + d[i].mtime
      + '</td><td>' + (d[i].type==='file' ? d[i].size : '-')
      + '</td></tr>\n';

  r+='</tbody></table>';
  document.body.innerHTML=r;
}
</script>

<script> // JSONP        Use your own preferred JSON(P) fetchmethod
/* callback */
foo([
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"????", "type":"other", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:17:52 GMT" }
]);
</script>
```

Some extra inspiration might be found in:

- [nginx-autoindex-js](https://github.com/kstep/nginx-autoindex-js) (a JavaScript frontend for Nginx JSON autoindex format)
- or [pretty-autoindex](https://github.com/spring-raining/pretty-autoindex)
  (currently has a ['bug'](https://github.com/spring-raining/pretty-autoindex/blob/master/src/pretty-autoindex.js#L160): it hides size when type=directory instead of correct behavior of hiding size when type!=file)

**Sources:**

- excellent help on the #nginx communitiy support IRC channel (on freenode) from user 'benbrown', thanks for the help in testing and pointing me to the relevant parts of the nginx source code
- http://lxr.nginx.org/ident?_i=ngx_http_autoindex_json
- http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c#0693
- official unit tests: 
  https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx-tests/autoindex_format.t